# SDL is pure opengl or not? if it is what are the differences?

Tags: sdl

I my collage i have to do a assignment in opengl and they intimidate us to do that in pure opengl. What it is just simply create and shown a transparent cube and put table inside it all of the model must create by the program they can't import by other modeling software like blender, 3dmax etc. And also they expect very high level lighting atmosphere in that cube. I am new to side and i heard that SDL is a game engine.

I wonder if i use SDL in my assignment may i end up with zero mark if it is not contain opengl? If there is good way to do this simple task please let me know!

Comment: [so] is not the place to clarify the requirements of your assignment. If your tutor says 'pure OpenGL' presumably that's what he means. If you have some other idea you should clarify it with him.

Comment: We can't straight write opengl have to use some libs and what they are how they different in opengl?

Comment: SDL != OpenGL. OpenGL is a library. OpenGL may be used in conjunction with other libraries.  If your assignment is to use OpenGL, then you'd darn well better learn as much as you can about OpenGL.  Start with OpenGL, and go as far as you can with OpenGL.  If you need to add other libraries (for example, with [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/), [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-index.html) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html)) ..,. then ask your professor.  But START with your ASSIGNMENT first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, SDL is not a game engine and it is not pure OpenGL.  However, you can build pure OpenGL applications using the windowing API that SDL gives you.  SDL is just one of many options for window management and GL context creation.

SDL can set up a window for you, can set up the OpenGL context, and handle user input.  From there, you can write pure OpenGL and render your cube or whatever.  If you have not used OpenGL or SDL before, then you probably have a lot of work ahead of you.

As another difference, SDL does have an additional 2D rendering API.  If your assignment is to do 3D with OpenGL, then obviously DO NOT use this 2D API.